# Start script not working

Tags: script, javascript

I have a script that starts my GPIO website server.  This allows my phone etc to accress the switches that control certain elements in my camper

I would like it to start at after boot in the case of power or other failure

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/webserver/gpio
node webserver.js
```

I have tried various ways I found on google but nothing seems to work. The script file has been made executable and it works when I click on it on the desktop, but as this Pi is a blind machine, accessing it to start the server may be hard

Any help appreciated

Comment: "I have tried various ways I found on google but nothing seems to work." List them and for each explain why it did not work.

Comment: What is a "GPIO website server"?

Comment: Its a webserver that enables me to control the GPIO pins from anydevice on its network

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use crontab -e adding a line with @reboot to start your script or (a much better option IMHO) make use of systemd services. Have a look at this post: [link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133602/mqtt-driven-python-servers-not-working-when-launched-by-crontab-e-reboot/133614#133614)

Comment: I have tried crontab 
@reboot /home/pi/Desktop/startup.sh

I have tried using superscript in the .bashrc file while gave the result "-bash: ./superscript: Permission denied"

I have tried using this "Put a script containing the command in your /etc directory. Create a script such as "startup.sh" using your favorite text editor. Save the file in your /etc/init.d/ directory. Change the permissions of the script (to make it executable) by typing "chmod +x /etc/init.d/startup.sh".

I have also tried adding it to "sudo nano /etc/rc.local"

All the above failed to start the process

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using rc.local and this line

> su pi -c 'node /home/pi/webserver/gpio/webserver.js < /dev/null &'